# Adding a ssh key to a user without ssh-copy-id

Tags: linux, ssh

If I have a host I want to be able to connect to and I currently have a keyboard and monitor plugged in, how would I copy a key to a user so I can connect as that user remotely. Essentially I want to do the same thing as ssh-copy-id but without having to be able to connect over ssh first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keys are stored in a text file under `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

To add a new key just copy the contents of the *.pub file of your key to a new line in this file.

Some more information is available [on the SSH web site](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/).

Comment: When doing this manually, **also make sure the file and directory permissions are set correctly.** The `authorized_keys` file should be owned by either the user that is being authorized, or by root, and **not be writeable by anyone else**. The same applies to the `~/.ssh` directory and the user's home directory. Otherwise `sshd` will ignore the `authorized_keys` file as there is a possibility that another user may have had write access to it.

Answer (score 1):

For example, use the commands below:

```
scp name_of_public_key.pub root@<remote IP address>:</home/user_home_folder or /root>
```

Then ssh log to remote host
and go to home folder of user

```
cd
```

or

```
cd /home/name_of_user
```

then type:

```
cat name_of_public_key.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Public key is added to end of file authorized_keys. Public key is not secret.

Comment: The question says, "_without having to be able to connect over ssh first_," but `scp` uses SSH to connect.

Answer (score 1):

This oneliner will automate the process:

```
cat .ssh/id_ecdsa.pub | xargs -i ssh NameOfServer "echo {} >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

This script cats your public key, pipes it to exargs using the `-i` flag that will pass the piped in output to any `{}`. You then ssh into your target server and echo your pubkey into the authorized key file, giving you sshkey access.

However, it will fail if the target machine doesn't have a `.ssh` folder or `authorized_keys` file., so the following script solves that with a bash conditional:

```
cat .ssh/id_ecdsa.pub | xargs -i ssh $1 "if [[ ! -e .ssh/authorized_keys ]]; 
then mkdir .ssh; touch .ssh/authorized_keys; fi; echo {} >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

The if statement checks to if the target directory exists, and exits, or creates it first and then exits.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which says, "_without having to be able to connect over ssh first_."

Comment: I read it as 'not using ssh-copy-id', since that was the title. Also, fundamentally, we're just adding an entry into the authorized_keys file, so cat'ing your public key and echoing it into .ssh/authorized_keys is generalizable to 'paste your pubkey into authorized_keys'